# How do I load this yml file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, yaml

I received this yml data file from a colleague who is unreachable. I need to load it to get the data, but I'm not sure how:

```
---
- !ruby/object:Question
  concise_attributes:
  - !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
    name: id
    value_before_type_cast: 1
  - !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
    name: name
    value_before_type_cast: Trip Summary
  - !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
    name: question
    value_before_type_cast: Please state your general feelings about itinerary, the
      group, and the operations. How did it go overall?
  - !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
    name: created_at
  - !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
    name: updated_at
  new_record: false
  active_record_yaml_version: 2
- !ruby/object:Question
  concise_attributes:
  - !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
    name: id
    value_before_type_cast: 2
  - !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
    name: name
    value_before_type_cast: Itinerary
  - !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
    name: question
    value_before_type_cast: Did you and the clients like the itinerary? If not, why
      not? How could it be improved? Was it accurate? Did you make any adjustments
      to the itinerary? Please describe any special things you did on the trip that
      were not part of the itinerary.
  - !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
    name: created_at
  - !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
    name: updated_at
  new_record: false
  active_record_yaml_version: 2
```

My first guess was to use the yaml_db gem, and then YAML::load_file itself directly, but I get the error:

```
ArgumentError: undefined class/module Question
```

Even though there is a Question model in the app"

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to have been encoded with [ActiveModel::AttributeSet::YAMLEncoder](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/master/ActiveModel/AttributeSet/YAMLEncoder#decode-instance_method). You can use the `decode` method to parse the yaml file.  The use of the `concise_attributes` is idiosyncratic to YAMLEncoder.

[Rails Source Code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/260b273106168ba7a122c76c79a3b7f4a3209559/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_set/yaml_encoder.rb)

EDIT: While the file is under ActiveModel, to load it in a console use `ActiveRecord::AttributeSet::YAMLEncoder`

Comment: Read the docs, but not obvious how to decode the "file". The #decode signature is decode(coder), but not sure what the coder is or how to convert the file to that.

Comment: I believe the coder will be `Question`. In `#encode(attribute_set, coder)` we have `coder["concise_attributes"]` which looks like `!ruby/object:Question` in your file.

Comment: Perhaps, but how do get the contents of this file into this method? I don't see how this instance method can fully work. Could you provide a code snippet?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::AttributeSet::YAMLEncoder.new(nil).decode(YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/path/to/question.yaml"))`

Comment: Interestingly: ActiveRecord::AttributeSet::YAMLEncoder.new(nil).decode(YAML.load_file("...../question.yml")) => NameError (uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::AttributeSet)
irb(main):005:0>

Comment: Rails 4? It is only available in Rails 5.  So here's what we do.  Go [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rails/rails/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_set/yaml_encoder.rb) and copy the raw code.  Paste that into a rails console.  Then you can do `ActiveModel::AttributeSet::YAMLEncoder.new(nil).decode(YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/path/to/question.yaml"))`. Note it is now back to `ActiveModel`

Comment: $ rails -v Rails 5.2.1; $ ruby -v ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin18]

Comment: Either way this gives the same error since YAML.load_file is what's throwing the error. It never makes it to #decode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186070/discussion-between-tom-and-pixelearth).